# add onclick event of specific element (without id or class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get attribute value (data-resource-id) in  tag. But this tag don't have id or class.  I just need  inside  show alert when clicked.  This is my code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<div class="x">
<tr data-resource-id="first"> //will show alert "first" when clicked
<tr data-resource-input="second">//show nothing when clicked
</div>
<div class="y">
<tr data-resource-id="first"> //show nothing when clicked
</div>
```

this is my javascript code:

```
$('.x').on('click','????',function(){
  var resourceid = $(this).attr('data-resource-id');
    alert(resourceid);
})
```

I don't know what code to write in '????'. What code should i write?

Comment: It depends on how specific you want to be. Do you want this event to fire for every `<tr>` on the page? Every element with the attribute `data-resource-id`? The first `<tr>` in every `<tbody>`? Only those where the `data-resource-id` is `first`? We can't give you an accurate answer for filling in the `????` without knowing more - it's like a mad-lib without instructions. Side-note: You can't use dashes in a javascript variable name. (Unless  you want to use `["this-notation"]` but it seems hardly necessary.)

Comment: @TylerRoper — I think it's probably safe to assume OP wishes every click on any element with the attribute `[data-resource-id]` to be handled by the callback

Comment: @ChaseMoskal Not sure why that would be safe to assume. It seems that isn't the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This updated version of your code might work for you

```
$(document).on('click', '.x [data-resource-id]', function() {
  const resourceId = $(this).attr('data-resource-id');
  alert(resourceId);
})
```

- Note, your original code had a variable named `resource-id` — but hyphens are illegal in javascript identifiers. So you must correct that variable name to `resourceId` instead
- `'????'` became `'.x [data-resource-id]'` so that clicks to anything matching that selector are handled
- `var` became `const` for good measure
- Corrected tab consistency

Comment: Thank you. but, i have more than one <tr> with that attributes . I just need <tr> inside <div class="x"> show alert when clicked. i try 
$('.x').on('click', '[data-resource-id]', function() { 
but doesn't work

Comment: @Galang: That would be `$(document).on('click', '.x [data-resource-id]',... Rest is the same`. That is basic selector usage here.

Answer (score 1):

Get all the  tags that have your attribute and value:

```
'tr[data-resource-id="first"]'
```

Get just the first  tag that matches your attribute and value:

```
'tr[data-resource-id="first"]:first'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute as selector. As below

```
  $('.x').on('click','tr[data-resource-id="first"]:first',function(){
  var resourceid = $(this).attr('data-resource-id');
    alert(resourceid);
})
```